# Prepopulated sqlite file in the app bundle. What happens after the existing users update?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I have an app on the store which points to the appname.sqlite file in the document directory.Here's the old code:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyApp.sqlite"];

 NSError *error = nil;

_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];

if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption : @YES,NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption : @YES}; error:&error]) {

    abort();
}
```

I now want to give an update. The new feature being a prefilled .sqlite database which is there in the bundle.See the following

```
NSURL *storeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyNewPrefilled" ofType:@"sqlite"]];
```

It would work ok on the fresh installation the app.But what happens to the users who have logged in and have a lot of data saved in the db (old sqlite in the app directory)? I would lose it because I now am pointing to the .sqlite in the app bundle (MyNewPrefilled.sqlite) and not the app directory one. How do I get the old data back from the old sqlite file of doc directory to my new one in the bundle?

FYI: I use code data migration already (involving version numbers in datamodels) which works ok when i change datamodel in updates.

Comment: Is the data you want to copy static data? Or will the user change it?

Comment: Note that the file in the bundle is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommends to use two persistent stores (in the same model) to separate data that is user generated and data that is static. Presumably, if your data is static, you should do exactly that and have a read-only store for the static data. See for example [Configurations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdMOM.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002328-SW3) in the Core Data Programming Guide.

Another approach is

1. to copy the bundle seed database into the documents directory, and then
2. read the data from the old store and
3. copy it to the new one.
4. Finally, you can delete the old store.

Comment: Yes my data is static. Read only.

Comment: I have been thinking of reading the data from the old store and copying into the new problem. Thats exactly what I posted the question for.
my problem : How do I do that? How exactly do i "read the data from the old store and copy it to the new one"?

Comment: Just fetch everything from the old store, loop through the results, insert new entities with the same data into the new store.

Comment: I went the "Configuration" way. And Thanks!! It works!
Thanks a tonn!